# How do I insert a demo user for testing?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm working through a unit testing tutorial in order to test user access.  Here's my test class

```
class TestTodo(TransactionCase):

    def setUp(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(TestTodo, self).setUp(*args, **kwargs)
        user_demo = self.env.ref('base.user_demo')
        self.env = self.env(user = user_demo)
        return result

    def test_record_rule(self):
        "Test per user record rules"
        Todo = self.env['todo.task']
        task = Todo.sudo().create({'name': 'Admin Task'})
        with self.assertRaises(AccessError):
            Todo.browse([task.id]).name
```

When I run the test, I'm getting this error

```
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: ERROR: test_record_rule (odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo.TestTodo)
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:  Test per user record rules
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:    File "c:\users\brubin\documents\odoo-dev\custom-addons\todo_app\tests\test_todo.py", line 9, in setUp
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 785, in ref
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 1091, in xmlid_to_object
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 1075, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:    File "<decorator-gen-5>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tools\cache.py", line 87, in lookup
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 1064, in xmlid_lookup
2017-08-20 17:02:19,861 25460 ERROR todo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:  ValueError: External ID not found in the system: base.user_demo
```

I assume this is because I don't have the demo user in my database (I created this database with the `-d` flag to `odoo-bin` rather than creating it through the database manager).  Is there a way that I can add the demo user without having to delete and recreate my database?  I tried going to Users in Odoo and creating a new user named demo, but the test still errors.  I can see the demo user in the `res_users` table and it looks identical in that table to the demo user in `res_users` that's in a database where I did install demo data.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have the user setup in your database, you'll need to make sure that you have an external id of "base.user_demo" setup. If you already have the user:

1. Activate developer mode
2. Navigate to Settings > Technical > Sequences & Identifiers
3. Find the external id for your current user and update the identifier name

If you wanted to start over with a fresh user, you could also define an XML record along the lines of:

```
<!--
This will generate an external identifier
of "{your custom module name}.user_demo"
-->

<record id="user_demo" model="res.users">
    <field name="name"/>

    ...
</record>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in step #3.  I followed your first two steps and found the demo user, but I'm not sure what to do now.  Here's the user https://imgur.com/a/yXBoO

Comment: I assumed there was not currently a `base.demo_user` external id already in the system. So things look good here. Not sure why your test cannot reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, same code for same ebook. I just deleted the database and reran odoo-bin. The error message disappeared.